# How Can I view MySql Fulltext Indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-indexing

1. Does MySql Fulltext search use indexing?
2. If so, how can I view the Index entries table?

I can view the Index Statistics with VIEW query. But, I just wanted to view the index record entries table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - FULLTEXT indexes, not regular indexes
2. See [Display Full-Text Index information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/myisam-ftdump.html)

I linked to the 4.1 MySQL docs, but you can pick the appropriate version in the upper left corner.