# Way to retrieve MySql Fulltext indexs information from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I asked [How to view MySql Fulltext Indexs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801715/how-to-view-mysql-fulltext-indexs) and got [myisam_ftdump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/myisam-ftdump.html) as answer. But it's just a command line tool and I need to retrieve those information from PHP.

**Is there any way to retrieve MySql Fulltext indexs information from PHP?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look, and what you're asking for doesn't appear to be very common.  The simplest solution I can see is to use PHP's [EXEC command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run the myisam_ftdump command, dumping the output file as a txt in a folder that you can access from PHP:

```
exec('myisam_ftdump yourtable 3 > /var/folder/yourFTindex.html')
```

The alternative would be a scheduled task or cron job to execute the command, but you'll have to code up your PHP to turn the output into what you want.